# nnn file manager image opens in web browser

Tags: fedora, file-management

When I open a image in nnn, it opens it in my default web browser rather than feh. I have tried png and jpg format. I also tried to find a configuration file but had hard time trying to find it. I also built the nnn from source and still it opens the image in the web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default application for the mime type correctly using

```
xdg-mime default application mimetype(s)
```

For more info please see https://github.com/jarun/nnn/issues/583